# Bipolar transistor switch base current calculation example from PEFI seems wrong?

Tags: transistors, current, bjt, base

I'm reading through [Practical Electronics for Inventors, 3rd edition](http://mhprofessional.com/product.php?isbn=0071771336), on bipolar transistors, and they provide this example of a transistor switch:

[image]

I'm a bit confused by the calculation at the bottom for the base current:

\$I_{B} = \frac{V_{E} + 0.6V}{R_{1}} = \frac{0V + 0.6V}{R_{1}}\$

Shouldn't the base current be calculated as follows?

\$+V_{CC} = V_{R_{1}} + V_{BE} + V_{E}\$

\$+V_{CC} = I_{B}*R_{1} + V_{BE} + V_{E}\$

\$+V_{CC} = I_{B}*R_{1} + 0.6V + 0V\$

\$I_{B} = \frac{+V_{CC} - 0.6V}{R_{1}}\$

Comment: You sound correct to me.

Comment: FYI for those also reading PEFI, there is an extensive unofficial errata for the Third Edition can be found at http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/practical-electronics-for-inventors-3rd/

Comment: @cdwilson  I'm not too keen on the idea of having [relatively obscure and not very widely used] abbreviations for book titles as tags.  You're welcome to contest this in meta.

Comment: @NickAlexeev do I just start a new topic in the meta SE and link this question?  I've never used meta before, just curious what the normal procedure is for these types of things

Comment: @cdwilson  Yes, you can do that.  The customs in the meta are more relaxed than in the main section.

Comment: @NickAlexeev FYI, looks like this question has already been asked/answered http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/tags-for-specific-books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree with you. When the switch is on, all the charge flowing through the resistor can only flow through the base-emitter junction of the transistor. The voltage across \$R_1\$ is \$V_{CC}-V_{BE}  = V_{CC} - 0.6\mathrm V\$, making the current \$\frac{V_{CC}-0.6\mathrm{V}}{R_1}\$.